# Button control template not working

Tags: wpf, templates, button

i am written the following xaml code:

```
    <Window x:Class="ImageScrollDemo.View.TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="TestWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="NextImageButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Image Source="..\Images\#next.png" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource NextImageButtonStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The window is rendered blank. i don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Image Source="..\Images\#next.png" ... />
```

Check the file name for the image and verify it does actually contain a `#` character.

Also, try using a static resource:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource NextImageButtonStyle}" />
```

Comment: That didn't work Bernard....the image file does have the # prefix. I am able to see the image in the design view in VS, but when i run the application the window is blank.

Comment: Very interesting. If you create a new window from scratch and use the XAML above in there, does it render in the WPF Designer? If it does, I don't see why it wouldn't render outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: well i got it working...i simply removed the # prefix from the image file name and from the XAML image source and now it's rendering the image. thanks, i appreciate you support.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note: Try specifying TargetType using Type syntax

```
<Style x:Key="NextImageButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

Reference: [MSDN Style.TargetType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx)

Using the key to refer to the resource may be enough, but an incorrect TargetType could interfere.